# click and change events are not working for Angular 6 Datatables Responsive extension

Tags: datatables, onclick, angular6, buttonclick, angular-datatables

I use Angular 6 datatables for show data in the frontend. I used responsive extension to show more data as described in 
https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/extensions/responsive

```
 <table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="row-border hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Category Name</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Is Enable</th>
                                <th>Sub Categories</th>
                                <th>update</th>
                                <th>delete</th> 
                                <th>Extra Data</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr *ngFor="let data of vehicleCategoryData; let i = index">
                                <td>{{data.categoryName}}</td>
                                <td>{{data.description}}</td>
                                <td>{{data.isEnable}}</td>
                                <td>{{data.subCategory.length}}</td>                                   
                                <td><i class="fa fa-edit" (click)="update(i)"></i></td>
                                <td><i class="fa fa-trash-o" (click)="delete(i)"></i></td> 
                                <td>{{data.extraData}}

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

also my dtOptions are defined as follows.

```
dtOptions: any =  {
pagingType: 'full_numbers',
pageLength: 5,
  columns: [{
    title: 'Category Name',
    data: 'categoryName'
  }, {
    title: 'Description',
    data: 'description'
  }, {
    title: 'Is Enable',
    data: 'isEnable'
  },{
    title: 'Sub Categories',
    data: 'sub'
  },
{
    title: 'update',
    data: 'up'
  },
{
    title: 'delete',
    data: 'del'
  },
{
    title : 'Extra Data',
    data : 'sc',
    className : 'none'
}],
  responsive: true
  };
```

So everything works fine. but

```
(click)="update(i)"
(click)="delete(i)"
```

events are not working. How can i solve this problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem by using the [listHiddenNodes function](https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.0/).

First i imported the Responsive variable in the component

```
import Responsive from 'datatables.net-responsive';
```

then i put this code on the dtOptions

```
this.dtOptions = {
    responsive: {
        details: {
            renderer: Responsive.renderer.listHiddenNodes()
        }
    },
};
```

That's all!